# Can I add a special price on my standard tier pricing?

Tags: price, tierprice, special-price

I have set a promotional action in the magento admin by adding a special price on product level.
The products have also a tierpricing system.
I would like to also add a special price on the tierprice values as part of the promotional action.
I am eagered to hear advice on how to handle this issue.

Comment: So do you want the special price to override the tier pricing for the time of the special?   Or are you asking if it will take the tier pricing and add (or subtract?) a certain amount?  Need slight clarification.